# RAILS 5 request.host is coming wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Wondering where I am doing wrong. But in production rails 5 app, when I try with request.host its coming as "app.mysite.com, app.mysite.com". Because of this complete application redirections are going wrong. Any one is facing the same issue? or any solution for this?

Comment: check your host value in production.rb or in your configuration files @Ramu

Comment: @wasipeer there is no host value mentioned there. action_mailer default host is mentioned.  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'https://app.mysite.com'}

Comment: then the issue will be in your config (in puma or etc)

Comment: @Ramu I have replied to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can find the host name by different way like below

```
  require 'resolv'
  Resolv.getname(request.remote_ip)
```